# I am unable to access Json data and display it in table using axios in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to access json data using hooks and display it in the

tag but it is showing error-"TypeError: states.map is not a function".I also used Array.from() to convert my json to array and it did not showed any error but also did not display anything.

```
  var rows=[{}];
  export default function Mainpage() {
const [states, setstate] = useState([]);
const getLatestJSPost = () => {
    const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/Displaydo";
    axios
    .get(API_URL)
    .then((response) => {
        
        // rows = Array.from(response.data);

        console.log(response.data);
        setstate(response.data)

    })
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getLatestJSPost();        
        
    }, [])
return (
    <div>
        <p>Hello</p>
        { states.map((ndata) => { 
                return <p key={ndata.doc_id}> {ndata.doc_id} </p>
                })}  
    </div>
)
```

}

The conole.log(response.data) looks like
[Output of console.log(response.data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0wh4.png)

Comment: So `response.data` isn't an array. We've no idea what it **is** or what data you want to treat like an array.

Comment: 1. How does your response.data look like? Is it Array?

Comment: Could you show us the result of `console.log(response.data)`

Answer (score -1):

you can do it this way:

```
 <div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    {states.length>0 && states.map((ndata) => { 
            return <p key={ndata.doc_id}> {ndata.doc_id} </p>
            })}  
</div>
```

Comment: That won't help. The problem is that the element doesn't have a map function (meaning it isn't an array at all, not that it is an array with nothing in it)